# jQuery Submit and the Heisenberg Effect

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to do a form.submit that will call a non-static event on the server side and force a full postback; however, I am encountering an example of the Heisenberg Effect. If I put a breakpoint on line 3 of code below, the code-behind gets the message and the submit works. If I put the breakpoint on line 4 instead, the submit fails. The server code actually gets the event, but the client doesn't seem to want to wait for the server to do its thing. The correct function should be that line 4 should never be executed.

```
1) function LoginSubmit() {
2)    $("#diagnostics").text("LoginSubmit started");
3)    $("#<%=btnLoginSubmit.ClientID %>").click();
4)    $("#diagnostics").text("LoginSubmit failed");
5)    }
```

Is there a way for me to wait for the server to get and process the btnLoginSubmit event message?

The code below is called when the user clicks the Logout button on the screen.

```
   function Logout() {
        $("#loginStatus").text("Logged out");
        $("SPAN[id*='lblLoginStatus']").text("");
        $("SPAN[id*='lblLoggedInUserName']").text("");
        $("#userId").text("");
        $("#menuId").text("");
        $("SPAN[id*='spanBtnLogout']").hide();
        $("SPAN[id*='spanBtnLogin']").css("display:inline;");
        $("SPAN[id*='spanBtnLogin']").show();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "LoginService.asmx/Logout",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: "{}",
            success: function (data, status) {
                $.cookie("LoggedInUserId", null);
                $.cookie("LoggedInMenuId", null);
                $.cookie("LoggedInUserName", null);

                LoginSubmit();  // Force a postback
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Logout function failed: " + XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: If line 4 is to never be executed, what is the point of the code that would live at line 4?

Comment: Nickpick: you're referring to the [Observer effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_effect_%28physics%29), not the [Heisenberg Uncertainty Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_Uncertainty_Principle).

Answer (score 2):

No, that's not possible without using AJAX. And I doubt the submit is failing, I would imagine that its just displaying the message. The program flow doesn't stop because you call a DOM element's `click()` function.

**Update**: Try this instead to get the C# button event to fire:

```
$("#<%=btnLoginSubmit.ClientID %>").trigger('click');
```

Comment: The C# event btnLoginSubmit_Click is not being called, and that's the whole point of doing it this way. I cannot see a way to accomplish what I need to with AJAX because that requires that the event be static and I need the event to be able to access properties and methods outside its scope, so it cannot be static, and hence AJAX won't work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript communicates with the server asynchronously. The script will not wait for the server to finish anything before proceeeding unless you build something in to your code to explicitly do that (e.g. ajax and a callback).

Under what circumstances do you want an error message shown? A POST will always result in the page being redrawn. It's still possible to have code that updates the DOM before that finishes (such as your code does now), but whatever happens on that post, this hunk of code will never know about it... because it will be gone and replaced with something else when the POST completes.

You should have your *server* code render an error message if the login fails, or use AJAX to update the DOM and do it without posting at all.

Comment: @jamietre - What I want is for the POST to happen exactly as you describe. The purpose of line 4 is to demonstrate that the POST is not happening. The server code will display a confirmation message IFF it gets called, but it isn't waking up, and that's the problem.

Comment: Is the upshot of your question, basically, that `$("#<%=btnLoginSubmit.ClientID %>").click();` is not causing a submit? e.g. it doesn't work at all with nothing but that line?

Comment: @jamietre - it works if I pause the program on line 3 in FireBug and then click continue. If there is no breakpoint, the code-behind doesn't get the event call.

Comment: Please post some more code, e.g. how is that function called to begin with? What happens after it returns? Even though the server-side click event does not fire, does the page post at all, e.g. does the `Page_Init` event fire? If you *remove* line 4 entirely (not pause it on line3) does it post?

Comment: @jamietre - More code posted. Taking out line 4 does not affect the results

Comment: So it looks like you're using ajax to log out, and then trying to post the page afterwards? If you can't do everything you need through the service, then why not just cut to the chase and have the "logout" button post normally? Call the code in the service from the page codebehind if you need to. I can't think of a good reason to post a page right after doing an ajax query... either do it through ajax, or post and do everything there.